# Mousebites around a round PCB

Tags: altium

I'm currently preparing a production panel with one round pcb in it.
I want to fix it in the panel with mousebites.

When I do 'Create primitives from board shape' to get 3mm route path, it results in a lot of small pieces.

[image]

It is a overlapping mix of arcs and tracks.

It is difficult to fit a mousebites structure here.
What am I doing wrong?

Is there a smart way to do this?
Can I use keepout layer here to push away the created route path pieces?

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Comment: You would be better off creating an arc and setting the radius to your desired value, rather than creating primitives from the board shape

Answer (score 1):

All border routing can be designed using the keepout layer.